# How to override devise redirection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to override devise in a such way that when  user sign up or login  to redirect him to `show_home_url` instead of `root_path(home#index)`.But i am not sure if  `after_sign_up_path_for` or `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` is what i need.Also whatever choice that is can anybody please show me how to implement that? i am a begginner in ruby.Here is  [Devise registration controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) Thank you very much.

```
      class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

         def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for( resource)

         end

         def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)

         end

         end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, you should be able to do this:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  show_home_path
end
```

See the [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) for a [similar example](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)